# Should we show respect to our gadgets?

Tags: quran, halal-haram, adab, respect

Muslims who use gadgets (Mobile phones, Video/Audio players) also use them to listen to Qur'an. Since our gadgets are now transformed into casings that holds Qur'an,

- Should we show them the same respect as we would to a Qur'an casing?
- Is it permissible to walk in to impure places like Toilets with the gadget inside our pockets?
- Should we protect it from contact with our feet, etc.?
- Or should we not bother about this as it is at the end a collection of bits (0's and 1's)?

Comment: Not an answer, but something to think because some people have adhaan as their ringtone. What if it goes off in toilet?

Comment: @tabrez : you would find ur answer here [link](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11892/is-it-allowed-in-islam-to-load-quran-into-smart-phone-as-pdf-or-audio-format/11900#11900)

Answer (score 1):

**According to scholars, it depends if the application is running.**

If it's running and the Quran verses are on the screen, then you should be in state of wudu (ritual purity).

What is forbidden is to make the name of God (or any part of His speech) appear in a improper place, or to touch/read it in an improper state.

You can see a full answer [here](http://www.daruliftaa.com/node/6501).

---

Little remark: So you should avoid to use a wallpaper with the name of Allah on your phone...or avoid using it in improper places.

You should also avoid Quran samples as ringtones as it could ring in an improper place.

*And Allah Knows Best*

Comment: welcome to [islam.se]. Please properly [edit] the comment into the answer.

Comment: and avoid quranic ringtones, to add to your answer.