# Is it allowed in Islam to load Quran into smart phone as pdf or audio format

Tags: quran, wudu, quran-recitation

Can someone please answer my following questions:

-is it allowed to load Quran into smart phone as pdf or audio format?

-if loading allowed then is it allow to read or listen Quran from smart phone without wudhu?

-can i touch or keep the smart phone in my pocket if Quran is loaded in it as pdf or audio format when i don't have wudhu?

-is it allowed to enter toilet when i have the smart phone in my pocket where Quran is loaded as pdf or audio format?

-can i recite without wudhu any verse/Sura of Quran that i memorized?

It would be good if you can provide any reference of Quran and Hadith for it or at least any fatwa or book by well known Arab Sheikh.

jazakallah khairan

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should we show respect to our gadgets?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8965/should-we-show-respect-to-our-gadgets)

Comment: Anything that's not covered there is covered in these questions: [Physical Quran and mobile Quran](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/14932/11593) and [Can I read Qur'an from a monitor when I don't have wudu?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1235/11593)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assalaam brother . The answers to your questions are:

-- yes , there is no harm in having a copy of the Quran as  pdf or audios in your cell phone.

-- yes again , when you are reciting the Quran from smartphone , you are actually holding ur cell and not the Mushaf , so there is no harm.

-- yes , but remember , the Quran pdf or audio are stored in a binary format in ur cell which have no defined Religious existence except for when they are decoded. If u have the Quran on ur screen and u enter ,then it isn't allowed to go to the toilet with the audio playing or pdf opened.

--Among the requirements of holding the actual Quran, the place and the body needs to be purified (though there's some disagreement on touching the mushaf without wudhu) . For recitation , you just need to ensure that the place is clean (recitation not allowed in toilets etc) even if u havent made wudhu or are in state of Janabah , u can recite it if you have memorized those verses.

and Allah knows best.. please refer to the link in comments for references.. Barakallahu Feekum.. :)
Here are the references links in the answer as requested:

http://www.assimalhakeem.net/faq/105
http://new.spring.me/#!/dawaah/q/991632930
http://islamqa.info/en/106961

Comment: jazakallah khairan, very helpful information. just one point, you said when quranic versses are on screen by the decoding, can i touch the phone/phone screen when it displayed on sceen and can i recite and listen it from that mobile without wudhu when its displaying on screen?

Comment: yes you can .. because you are touching the screen and its not mushaf.. as for the toilet part , will it please us to have it on screen and enter?? its better to stay safe ..the word letters are visible at a place that isnt clean..

Answer (score 0):

- It's allowed to load the Quran as a pdf or an audio format on your smart phone or any device.  There's no prohibition in Quran or authentically proven sayings of Rasolullah that forbids us from transporting, writing, or printing it on other things.  If it wasn't allowed, we would have an ayah or Sahih hadith telling us.
- Yes, it's allowed to read the Quran without wudhu as wudhu is obligatory for prayer and not simply reciting the Quran on its own.
- You can enter the toilet with it, once again, there's no verse in the Quran that forbids it.
- You can recite from your memory without wudhu also.

If something is haraam to do, we need an ayah or an authentic statement coming from Rasolullaah explaining it to us.  None of the questions you've asked have ayahs or hadith making it impermissible.  If there's no evidence, then nothing can be forbidden, but taken on the general rule of permissibility.

Comment: but sometime people says that touching physical Quran is not allowed without wudhu and also entering toilet with quran loaded smart phone is some kind of dishonor to Quran. may be its related to fiqah, can you please explain this matter again in details if possible?